# can't get express session data from socket io connection

Tags: node.js, session, websocket, socket.io

Hello i'm having a problem to access express session data like I did on http connection.
Even when I copy the documentation edited by socket io on this link
https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-express-session#1st-use-case-socketio-only-retrieves-the-session-context i still can't access express session data.
there is my server

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const sessionStrategy = require('@middlewares/session_strategy/sessionStrategy');
const httpServer = require("http").Server(app);
const Server = require("socket.io").Server;


app.use(express.urlencoded({ 
  parameterLimit: 20, 
  extended: true,
  limit: '10mb'
}));
app.use(express.json({limit: '100mb'}));

// CORS
app.use(cors({
  origin: true,
  credentials: true
}));
app.use(sessionStrategy);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.set('trust proxy', 1);
}
const corsConfig = {
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
  methods: ["GET", "POST"]
};

const io = new Server(httpServer, {cors: corsConfig});
const wrap = middleware => (socket, next) => middleware(socket.request, {}, next);

io.use(wrap(sessionStrategy));

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // socket.request.session give undefined value
  console.log("Connexion", socket.request.session);
  socket.on("event_test", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(socket);
  });
  socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
    console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
  });
});

app.all('*', require("@middlewares/catchAllRoute"));

httpServer.listen(process.env.NODE_API_PORT, function () {
  console.log('App listening on port ' + process.env.NODE_API_PORT + ' ...');
});
```

and there is my client

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://localhost:9000", { 
  withCredentials: true
});

export default socket;
```

```
import socket_connection from "@/sockets_connections";
// the command is launched after a click
socket_connection.emit("event_test", {"test":"test"});
```

Comment: I get the cookie the session is not added to the socket object

Comment: socket io is in version 4.5.1

Comment: it works when i downgrade the version 2.5.1